# CSS - Sharing @Keyframes Ruleset with Animation-Direction and Animation-Fill-Mode?

Tags: javascript, css, animation

I have a simple blue square that I want to control with 2 buttons, *"Move Left"* and *"Move Right"*.

- **Move Left:**  Should move the blue square from the right to the left, fade the opacity from 0.5 to 1 and retain the last frame of the animation.
- **Move Right:**  Should move the blue square from the left to the right, fade the opacity from 1 to 0.5 and retain the last frame of the animation.

I want to share a single `@keyframes move` ruleset, but I'm confused with how `animation-direction` and `animation-fill-mode` should work together.

The first time the animation is fired is correct, whether the animation moves left or right, but after that it no longer animates as it should.

```js
const square = document.getElementById("square");

const leftButton = document.getElementById("left");
leftButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
    square.classList.remove("moveRight");
    square.classList.add("moveLeft");
});

const rightButton = document.getElementById("right")
rightButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
    square.classList.remove("moveLeft");
    square.classList.add("moveRight");
})
```

```css
#square {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: blue;
    margin-top: 20px;
    position: relative;
}
 
 .moveLeft {
     animation: move 1s linear normal forwards;
 }
 
 .moveRight {
     animation: move 1s linear reverse forwards;
 }
 
 @keyframes move {
     from {left: 100px; opacity: 0.5;}
     to {left: 0; opacity 1;}
 }
```

```html
<input type="button" id="left" value="MOVE LEFT">
<input type="button" id="right" value="MOVE RIGHT">

<div id="square"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it without an animation using `transition`.

```js
const square = document.getElementById("square");

const leftButton = document.getElementById("left");
leftButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
    square.classList.remove("moveRight");
    square.classList.add("moveLeft");
});

const rightButton = document.getElementById("right")
rightButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
    square.classList.remove("moveLeft");
    square.classList.add("moveRight");
})
```

```css
#square {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: blue;
    margin-top: 20px;
    position: relative;
  transition: transform 1s, opacity 1s;
}
 
 .moveLeft {
   transform: translateX(0);
   opacity: 1;
 }
 
 .moveRight {
  transform: translateX(100px);
   opacity: .5;
 }
```

```html
<input type="button" id="left" value="MOVE LEFT">
<input type="button" id="right" value="MOVE RIGHT">

<div id="square"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  However, in case I have a more complex animation, which requires using `animation` instead of `transition`, I'd like to know how to share a `@keyframes` ruleset.  For example, if the blue square has an initial opacity of 0, pressing "Move Left" should still animate the square with `to / from` or `0% 50% 100%` of an animation.

Comment: @TheDarkIn1978 you're welcome. I'm not sure why the animation isn't working. I can keep looking at it. Do you want me to delete this answer as it "isn't useful" or leave it as an alternate approach for anyone that finds this question in the future?

Comment: Don't delete the answer, i'm sure others may find it useful.  But please edit your answer if you find the solution.